# Differentiating in pyomo

Tags: pyomo

How can we differentiate constraints defined in pyomo with respect to particular variables, and multiply those expressions with another pyomo model component. I want to generate a constraint that involves the derivative of other constraints, ie: l1*dg1/dz + l2*dg2/dz = 0, where l1 and l2 are pyomo variables, g1 and g2 are other constraints in the model. Kindly help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `differentiate` function in `pyomo.core.base.symbolic`. There are a few faster implementations in the pipeline, but this should give you what you need. For a usage example, you can take a look at the [GDPopt solver code](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/1192c05d9cf84c318899bffc53181b72be760a6a/pyomo/contrib/gdpopt/GDPopt.py#L1263).